# Reading series of values in R

Tags: r

I have read a series of 332 files like below by storing the data in each file as a data frame in List.

```
files <- list.files()
data <- list()
for (i in 1:332){
  data[[i]] = read.csv(files[[i]])
}
```

The data has 3 columns with names id, city, town. Now I need to calculate the mean of all values under city corresponding to the id values 1:10 for which I wrote the below code

```
for(j in 1:10){
   req.data <- data[[j]]$city
}
mean(na.omit(req.data))
```

But it is giving me a wrong value and when I call it in a function its transferring null values. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you iterate through `j = 1:10` you assign `data[[j]]$city` to the object `req.data`. In doing so, for steps `j = 2:10` you are **overwriting** the previous version of `req.data` with the contents of the `j`th data set. Hence `req.data` only ever contains at any one time a single `city`'s worth of data and hence you are getting the wrong answer sa you are computing the mean for the last city only, not all 10.

Also note that you could do `mean(req.data, na.rm = TRUE)` to remove the `NA`s.

You can do this without an explicit loop at the user R level using `lapply()`, for example, with dummy data,

```
set.seed(42)
data <- list(data.frame(city = rnorm(100)),
             data.frame(city = rnorm(100)),
             data.frame(city = rnorm(100)))

mean(unlist(lapply(data, `[`, "city")), na.rm = TRUE)
```

which gives

```
> mean(unlist(lapply(data, `[`, "city")), na.rm = TRUE)
[1] -0.02177902
```

So in your case, you need:

```
mean(unlist(lapply(data[1:10], `[`, "city")), na.rm = TRUE)
```

If you want to write a loop, then perhaps

```
req.data <- vector("list", length = 3) ## allocate, adjust to length = 10
for (j in 1:3) { ## adjust to 1:10 for your data / Q
    req.data[[j]] <- data[[j]]$city    ## fill in
}
mean(unlist(req.data), na.rm = TRUE)

> mean(unlist(req.data), na.rm = TRUE)
[1] -0.02177902
```

is one way. Or alternatively, compute the mean of the individual cities and then average those means

```
vec <- numeric(length = 3)  ## allocate, adjust to length = 10
for (j in 1:3) {  ## adjust to 1:10 for your question
    vec[j] <- mean(data[[j]]$city, na.rm = TRUE)
}
mean(vec)
```

Comment: Thanks the edit helped me as I was looking for a solution with an implementation of loop. One further Q to it is when I am putting it inside a function and passing the id and city name as an argument and execute it, I get NA as answer and below warning message                  Warning message:
    In mean.default(unlist(req.data), na.rm = TRUE) :
       argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA              Any idea what could be the reason. Thnx

Comment: I'd ask a new question for that; it's not clear what your function looks like or how you are calling it.